# Override Back button to save data using SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, back-button

When using my app the users inputs data and the data is supposed to be saved. However at the moment the back button erases the data from the `EditText`. Here is my java file for the activity, this activity is activated by a button press from the Main Activity. I've already tried to override the back button with no success. Any suggestions?

```
public class NewLocation extends ActionBarActivity {

    public String coName;
    public String coAddress;
    public String coContact;
    public String sqFt;
    public String taxed;
    public String concerns;
    public EditText editCoName;
    public EditText editCoAddress;
    public EditText editCoContact;
    public EditText editSqFt;
    public EditText editTaxed;
    public EditText editConcerns;

    public static final String DEFAULT = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_location);
        findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(NewLocation.this, RoomList.class));
            }
        });

        editCoName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CoName);
        editCoAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CoAddress);
        editCoContact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CoContact);
        editSqFt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SqFt);
        editTaxed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Taxed);
        editConcerns = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Concerns);

        coName = editCoName.getText().toString();
        coAddress = editCoAddress.getText().toString();
        coContact = editCoContact.getText().toString();
        sqFt = editSqFt.getText().toString();
        taxed = editTaxed.getText().toString();
        concerns = editConcerns.getText().toString();


        LoadPreferences();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);

        outState.putString("coName", coName);
        outState.putString("coAddress", coAddress);
        outState.putString("coContact", coContact);
        outState.putString("sqFt", sqFt);
        outState.putString("taxed", taxed);
        outState.putString("concerns", concerns);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        coName = savedInstanceState.get("coName").toString();
        coAddress = savedInstanceState.get("coAddress").toString();
        coContact = savedInstanceState.get("coContact").toString();
        sqFt = savedInstanceState.get("sqFt").toString();
        taxed = savedInstanceState.get("taxed").toString();
        concerns = savedInstanceState.get("concerns").toString();

    }

    private void SavePreferences()
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("New Location Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putString("coName", coName);
        editor.putString("coAddress", coAddress);
        editor.putString("coContact", coContact);
        editor.putString("sqFt", sqFt);
        editor.putString("taxed", taxed);
        editor.putString("concerns", concerns);

        editor.apply();
    }

    private void LoadPreferences()
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("New Location Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        coName = sharedPreferences.getString("coName", DEFAULT);
        coAddress = sharedPreferences.getString("coAddress", DEFAULT);
        coContact = sharedPreferences.getString("coContact", DEFAULT);
        sqFt = sharedPreferences.getString("sqFt", DEFAULT);
        taxed = sharedPreferences.getString("taxed", DEFAULT);
        concerns = sharedPreferences.getString("concerns", DEFAULT);

        editCoName.setText(coName);
        editCoAddress.setText(coAddress);
        editCoContact.setText(coContact);
        editSqFt.setText(sqFt);
        editTaxed.setText(taxed);
        editConcerns.setText(concerns);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new_location, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.home:
                SavePreferences();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainPage.class));
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        SavePreferences();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are deleting data in another activity?

Comment: I think that is the case. The data shows on some occassions but if I hit back to the main activity and hit the button that is supposed to lead me to the `New Location` the data is deleted. How can I find where I am deleting the data?

Comment: My advise is to move all methods with shared preferences in every single place around your application to single class. This class should be singleton, after that you can easily see what is going on in yours shared preferences by looking for usages in your code.

Comment: Is it possible that my button that moves to `New Location` could be creating a new instance of the activity and not reopening the old instance of `New Location` that I entered the data into?

Comment: Every time after launching intent, activity is new instance. Only if you change launchMode it acts different. Have you checked that your SavePreferences method is always called?

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState` should still be able to work if I back out of that activity and reopen it right?

Comment: Read that: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save/restore the persistent state of the activity in `onSaveInstanceState`/`onRestoreInstanceState` methods. You already override those, so just call `SavePreferences`/`LoadPreferences` from them.

Overriding the back button is not a good idea and saving state in `onDestroy` is also not recommended. Either `onSaveInstanceState` or `onPause` is intended for that.

Comment: By just calling `SavePreferences`/`LoadPreferences` in `onSaveInstanceState`/`onRestoreInstanceState` the back button still erases all of my data and when i come back everything is empty.

Answer (score 0):

[Edited] You can try:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        SavePreferences();
        finish(); //<-- You need finish your activity after saved
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Change *return true*, to *return false*, then back button will work.

Comment: back button continues to not work even after changing true to false

Comment: I forgot the finish(); Try now!

Comment: back button now works however the data is still not being shown

Comment: not show because maybe your loadShared is wrong, review if that is able to get the data from shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

If the data needs to be saved whenever the user leaves that activity, you could approach the problem with a TextWatcher.  Override the onTextChanged() method of the TextWatcher with something like this:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (s.length > 0) coName = s;
}
```

And then override onPause() to save the state of your variables if necessary.

Comment: How does  a text watcher help?

Comment: So using TextWatcher will be instead of using SharedPreferences, so I'd remove all SharedPreference methods and use this, right?

Comment: The thought was to use the textwatcher to keep your variables updated to the latest non-zero length value input by the user, and then you can call your SavePreferences method in the onPause method, which gets called whenever your activity leaves the foreground.  The check for length is so that if the back key clears the field, the empty value does not override the last actual value.